# deploy project documentation to gitlab wiki using CI/CD pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, documentation-generation

I'm using `GitLab Community Edition v16.8.1`, and I'm using Doxygen/Sphinx to generate my documentation automatically as html files, is there a neat way to automate the deployment to wiki using the CI/CD pipeline?

- I have seen an [approach](https://gitlab.com/blex41/project-with-wiki-update/-/tree/master?ref_type=heads) for Javascript, but I will aprreciate it if somone has a better approach to deploy them automatically
- I tried to deploy the documentation to gitlab pages as [explained here](https://gitlab.com/pages/sphinx/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml?ref_type=heads#L15), but it turns that I don't have Gitlab pages feature in my Gitlab version

Tried both `public` and `wiki`, and it didn't work!

```yaml
  script:
    - sphinx-build -b html doc/source/ ./wiki/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - wiki
```

Comment: GitLab Pages [should also be available](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2016/12/24/were-bringing-gitlab-pages-to-community-edition/) in GitLab CE but you [need to enable and configure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/index.html) it.

Comment: @rveerd True, but currently since I don't have this feature enabled, I thought about going to wiki since I have it enabled by default.

Comment: The wiki does not contain HTML pages but Wikitext, so I do not think that is an alternative. You might be able to generate Wikitext instead of HTML but then you still need to import them into the wiki somehow.

Comment: @rveerd True, but also I can generate Markdown files instead of html